# In-app purchase failed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

My app has non-renewing subscription,
Our users are experiencing issues with our in-app purchase.
This happens from time to time, and not consistent.
Users are complaining that they made a purchase and they got charged but they weren't able to create the account.
We tested this many times, but we can't reproduce the issues.
Anyone have any idea what could have caused this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you tested as a regular user with or only in sandbox environment ? do you validate receipt in the app? or in your server

Comment: I tested it mostly in sandbox env, but it works in production env too, it's just not working from time to time. We even confirmed the same user tried it twice, first one didn't go through, second one did.